# foo.setText(bar) causes NullPointerException..what am i doing wrong?

Tags: java, android

I am creating an android app and needed to change the text of some textViews in one of my layouts. This is my code.

```
public void hudSetup() {
    Player stats = new Player(this);
    stats.open();
    String playerName = stats.getStringField(stats.KEY_NAME);
    String playerCity = stats.getStringField(stats.KEY_CITY);
    int playerHealth = stats.getIntField(stats.KEY_HEALTH);
    int playerEnergy = stats.getIntField(stats.KEY_ENERGY);
    int playerRank= stats.getIntField(stats.KEY_RANK);
    int playerCash = stats.getIntField(stats.KEY_CASH);
    stats.close();
    name.setText(playerName);
    city.setText(playerCity);
    energy.setText(playerEnergy);
    health.setText(playerHealth);
    cash.setText(playerCash);
    rank.setText(playerRank);

}
```

I have ensured all of my textViews are initialised. The code compiles, however when i run the app and the hudSetup() method runs, I get a nullPointerException.

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (java.lang.NullPointerException)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4282)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4197)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:138)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4140)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3757)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatReceiverFactory.newReceiver(LogCatReceiverFactory.java:57)
at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatPanel.deviceSelected(LogCatPanel.java:229)
at com.android.ddmuilib.SelectionDependentPanel.deviceSelected(SelectionDependentPanel.java:52)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.views.SelectionDependentViewPart.selectionChanged(SelectionDependentViewPart.java:67)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.DdmsPlugin$6.run(DdmsPlugin.java:690)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
... 22 more
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't seem to be related to your code... try reinstalling the Android SDK/plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TextView.setText(int)` uses the resource defined as an integer in R.java.
For your purpose, you might want to cast the integers to String first.

Like:

```
cash.setText(playerCash + "");
```

Or, like @Pedro said:

```
cash.setText(String.valueOf(playerCash));
```

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28int%29).

Comment: I had to wait a few minutes before it let me.

Comment: actually, many people agree that you should use `String.valueOf(int)` instead of the `xxx+""` trick